# Question Deletion Notification?

Tags: discussion, questions, notifications, deleted-questions

Is there no means of notifying a user why their question is deleted?  I just asked an honest and real question about the use of meta and the role of admins; when going to comment on an answer (a very good answer, I should add), I find that the question was deleted.  Is there any way to find why my question was deleted?

Comment: This question gets deleted in 3... 2... 1...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Notice of deletion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80460/183280)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### Vote for: [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted/closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted-closed)

...and then badger moderators into leaving comments prior to deletion.

Comment: Upboat for you.  Wish moderators actually did this.

Comment: Well voting alone is not enough, this case requires assassination :P

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you know why its been deleted...  The reality is we need to find a way for everyone in the community to get along or simply agree to disagree and remain respectful about it.

All sides need to be considerate and look/reflect inwards before pointing a finger at someone else...  The rollback wars are typically caused by 2 people.  If the author rolls it back, stop the war and flag the post if you feel strongly about it...  Let the mods be mods...

Comment: I genuinely do not know why the question was deleted.  It was a perfectly valid and reasonably asked (and non-accusatory) question about why moderators appeared to not be engaging in punitive action on meta given what was going on; this relates in a very serious manner to exactly what sort of site we can expect this (and by relation, SO) to be.  There were no rollbacks.  There was no finger-pointing.  There was valid questioning as to why things were (or not) happening.  Before it was deleted, there was a very good and reasonable answer posted from a moderator.

Answer (score -1):

Questions or answers that cause a lot of friction (as defined by downvotes, excessive comments, rude behavior, rollback/edit wars, etcetera) -- for whatever reason -- will be deleted.

There's no notification system for deletions.

Comment: Yes, but I contend that my question was not any of that; there was no blaming, no large numbers of downvotes, no excessive comments, nothing rude, no rollbacks; I got a perfectly valid and polite answer from a moderator, and I was in the midst of thanking him for a very reasonable reply, when the post was deleted.

Comment: @Mc: Discretion. They have it. You take the good, you take the bad, you take them both and there you have the facts of life. Just accept that they felt that it should be deleted and move on.