# Where is my question? Have you deleted it without telling me?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question Deletion Notification?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3394/question-deletion-notification)

May I ask you what happened to my last question on Stack Overflow?

Why didn't I receive any feedback or alert? Have you deleted it without telling me?

Comment: You should be able to see your activity from your profile.  I am sure you can find your question from there.

Comment: I have checked my profile. The question is  not there! Believe me!

Comment: What's the question title? The last one you seemed to have asked is `Entity Send to Server Problem`

Comment: 10k link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083155/design-and-technology-for-syncing-my-applications-data-with-a-database.

Comment: @ehsun - noise is also not welcome in SO, dunno why your question got deleted but I guess it was for good reason. Good for the community, I mean.

Comment: Hmm, looks like you asked [another question that's about to get deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086328/web-hosting-which-is-the-most-expensive-cost). Might I seriously suggest reading the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)?

Answer (score 14):

Your question was closed. Once a question is closed, users with more than 20k reputation may vote to delete it immediately, if they judge that the question does not have any redeeming value to the site. Once two days have passed, users with more than 10k reputation may do the same. Once a question accumulates three delete votes (more if the question was in positive vote territory), it's deleted.

In addition, moderators may delete question at any time (I believe). Finally, most anyone may vote to delete a question as spam or offensive, and once a question has six of those votes, it's gone.

That's the way Stack Overflow works - the community retains shared ownership over your question, once it's posted.

Comment: Ok it is the policy of the site, but is it liberal that you don't inform the asker that you have closed and deleted his question without his choice???

Comment: My question was open less than 24 hours! Is it really your policy? I need to revise the forums out there

Comment: I don't know about "liberal" - you're using that word in a strange context here. Generally, the site owners have maintained a policy of "low noise" - if a question has low value, don't raise a stink, just get rid of it.

Comment: The OP does make a good point though - people should know when their own questions are closed, and should be able to see the close reason and question comment thread; this will hopefully help people know what to avoid doing in the future.

Comment: @ehsun7b, I saw your question. If you want to be a part of this community, you're going to have to change your ways. Specifically, 1) don't promote your work in the guise of asking a question, and 2) don't lash out at others looking to help you.

Comment: At first I was shocked not seeing my question in the morning since I didn't receive any alert about deletion. The other thing is that you can see who started insulting in my question. The other thing is that I didn't want to promote anything and that's what made me angry that you professional guys who are older than me think I wanted to promote something over there, now I need to rewrite my question in a way that nobody.... forget it. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: I can distinguish between helping and insulting :)

Answer (score 10):

I looked at the question, and I fully understand why it was deleted.  The question was gratuitously self-promotional in its original form AND not answerable objectively.  Blatant self promotion is simply not on ...

The only point is whether users (in general) should be notified of their deleted questions ... or should still be able to see them.  IMO, that is covered by this meta question:  [Question Deletion Notification?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3394/question-deletion-notification)

Comment: I put the link of my project just because users be able to check the project specification in order to answer more precise answers, it is very funny that you take it as self-promoting. The project is not a new or fresh project that I need to promote it.

Comment: @ehsun7b, come on now. *"I have developed a password manager, MyPasswords which attracted people all over the world and won a competition on Linux Format about best Linux password manager."*

Comment: OK, is it really a bad thing??? Is it a commercial product??? I wanted to persuade the professionals that why I'm asking them to suggest a nice and pro solution. I really need to think more about.... The world is really becoming more funny, at least in the IT people.

Comment: The software won the competition more than 6 month ago, and the initial release was more than a year ago, why should I promote it here now??? It is really funny! I'm so happy to looked for the reason of deletion, this is the last thing I could guess as the reason.

Comment: @ehsun7b: Yes, it is a bad thing. It didn't add anything to your question, and served merely to promote your own product, which is frowned upon on SO. I'm glad you find it funny, though for some reason I doubt your sincerity.

Comment: No My question was edited by you, and I accepted the update since it still had the question, but today I saw that the question was deleted completely. That's why I guess it has another reason.

Comment: @ehsun7b, for what it's worth, your question was deleted by the co-founder of this site.

Comment: It is not important who deleted it! I just wanted to know why? Since today in the morning I was hoping to see some answers, but ...

Comment: @ehsun7b, read my answer again. Your question was deleted, most likely, because it was of poor quality and would not "make the Internet better", as the founders of SO are fond of saying. Specifically, your question was too broad to answer well within the Q and A structure of SO. In addition, you showed yourself not amenable to help in your follow-up comments. SO doesn't like to keep poor questions around, and so it was deleted. You clearly disagree with that action, as is your right, but don't claim now that you haven't seen an explanation.

Comment: At first I was shocked not seeing my question in the morning since I didn't receive any alert about deletion. The other thing is that you can see who started insulting in my question. The other thing is that I didn't want to promote anything and that's what made me angry that you professional guys who are older than me think I wanted to promote something over there, now I need to rewrite my question in a way that nobody.... forget it. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: @ehsun: You were asking a whole bunch of questions in one, none of which were fully formed. Focus! You get the best answers when you ask narrow detailed questions that are nonetheless likely to be useful to others. If it's too broad or too many questions are in the same SO question, it becomes impossible to answer: too many "well, that depends".