# Not able to see my latest question

Tags: support, deleted-questions

Very recently I had asked a question. I had received some very good answers and based on that I was able to solve my problem as well.

But after that, the question just vanished from my asked questions list. Actually I had asked a similar question in Jan'12 (maybe the subject line was same but I honestly do not remember) and the same was closed. I am able to view the old question but not the latest one. Is this the reason for not able see my latest question?

Comment: It is entirely possible that the question was deleted by the community.

Comment: Oh.. Then does the site inform about such an event? Ideally it should, right? Maybe send a mail or reflect in my account. Also the question wasnt so bad as to be deleted, i guess!

Comment: If it was a duplicate (or close to), then it was bad. If you had any votes on it, you can go to your account page to the reputation and click the checkbox near the bottom "show removed posts". You should then have a link you can post here, if it was indeed deleted and had votes.

Comment: [The idea's been floating around for a while.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3394/question-deletion-notification) But I think the decision was that notifying upon deletions will cause a lot of whining.

Comment: @Mysticial; even if there are a lot of whinings, still it is better notifying than deleting mysteriously. Also it might help the question poster to chalk out his next plan of action for his problem, other wise he will be in a state of confusion.

Comment: I also don't agree with the policy of silent deletions. I think the OP has the right to know why a post was deleted. For answers, you can still see whatever comments a mod leaves under it as well as a link to the FAQ. But for questions, it's nothing unless you have 10k...

Comment: @Oded; I just checked following your steps and indeed the question was deleted. Also there are some upvotes and some down votes to the question but I am not able to understand the "link" part you mentioned. Are you talking about link of the question? Please clarify.

Comment: @samar - Yes, a link to the question, so we can see it here. Users with 10k+ reputation can see deleted content as can moderators.

Comment: Oh.. ok.. There are 2 questions which got deleted. Both are similar questions. I am posting link for both the questions.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827435/how-to-perform-actions-on-a-web-browser-using-net-windows-application/9953279#9953279                         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810003/how-to-do-some-actions-on-web-browser-using-c-sharp-windows-application

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the questions are deleted. One of them asked

> I would like some direction on how to approach this problem. Maybe some good sites or some good code. Anything on this would be very helpful. I don't know if this is actually possible but I think it should be.

This isn't a question about solving a specific programming problem, like it should be on StackOverflow. There is no way of giving a single correct answer to such a question, so it is a very bad fit for a Q&A site.

The correct approach is to actually try something out yourself. If and when you run into any *specific* problems, post these and we will be happy to try to help you solve them. One problem per question will give you the most precise answers.

Comment: I think what you are talking about is for the older question. But for the latest question I was facing problems and so I had posed it. Any updates on that would be nice.

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about the first question because I was part of the community voting to close and delete that one. The second  question was removed by a moderator, likely because some other users complained about it. I don't have access to any details about that.

Comment: The second question was deleted for similar reasons as the first. You gave a list of steps, and then asked "Is any other better approach available?" That's not the kind of question you should be asking on Stack Overflow. I highly recommend that you read the [FAQ] before posting any more questions. @samar